# Google BigQuery parameter customer_id does not match regular expression when transferring data from Google Ads

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

When I tried to set up a transfer from my MCC Google Ads account to my BigQuery, it raises an error

```
Parameter customer_id with value xxxxxx does not meet the required regular expression: [\d-]+. Config name:
```

When I tried the individual customer ad account, it works, so only the main MCC does not work

Answer (score 0):

You get this because there's a space in the adwords customer ID field